# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gitpython==3.1.0

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, gitpython

I am having a problem where in the jenkins build pipeline, I get an error regarding gitpython version could not be found. My project consists of a requirement.txt file where I have already added the gitpython dependency as follows:

gitpython==3.1.0 also tried GitPython==3.1.0

The problem is, in my local venv, i do not get any error, but when my project is being pushed to jenkins pipe i get the error(see image attached). Do I need to do something additionally to make it work? I tried various other versions of gitpython  but for all of them, I get the same error in the build pipe.

[image: The Output]

Comment: you are using `--no-index --find-links` with a directory, so pip searches for package files **only** in that directory. Do you have the package there? if not why are you using this flags?

Comment: You are absolutely right, the package was not there. I added those packages in the folder along with it's dependencies and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `requirements.txt` to use the most recent version `gitpython==3.1.20`. You can also try something like: `gitpython>=3.1.0`.

Comment: Tried both before, and I still get the same problem